# How to get old Location value from the didUpdateToLocation method in swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, core-location, cllocationmanager

In Objective C, i got old location and new locations of the user 
using the following method

```
  - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

        if (oldLocation == nil) return;
        BOOL isStaleLocation = ([oldLocation.timestamp compare:self.startTimestamp] == NSOrderedAscending);
    ...
    }
```

Now i porting the code to Swift, i cant able to get the old location from the following  method

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {


        self.currentLocation = manager.location
}
```

Is there any way to get the old location or i missed anything?

Answer (score 0):

There is no longer an `oldLocation`so you will have to rely on the `timestamp` of the `CLLocation` returned. You can check it against the current time using `timeIntervalSinceNow` to know if it is new or not.

Comment: Is there any way to get exact old location?

Comment: The best thing to do is store it in a var as you receive it